# Django-rest-auth Facebook registration

Tags: facebook, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to implement facebook login with django-rest-auth (a rest wrapper for Allauth).
I have followed their tutorial (showing how to log in, http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html), but I am bit puzzled concerning the registration part.

The login view expects only a token but there is no Social Register view. Does this mean that django-rest-auth does not handle the registration of new users? Or that it is handled in a separate view?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django rest auth has the [`RegisterView`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L17), it will handles the user registration part and return the `Auth Token`. The [`LoginView`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py#L19) will takes the user credentials and validate the user and authentication.